# Intruders in Ubuntu 16.04, what exactly did they do?

Tags: postgresql, security, ubuntu, gzip

it seems i had an intruder in my ubuntu server, due to a misconfigured postgresql server (user without a password).

I noticed high CPU, and in my postgresql logs i noticed enteries like 
`stratum detected new block` and `pool set diff to 4236`. Ofcourse this means that someone used my server for mining bitcoins or something similar, and a compromised server means reinstall.

However, i'm interested in what the script that they ran exactly does, so i can be sure that they didn't do anything weird with the data in my database.

As far as my understanding about this goes, is that they use gzip to obfuscate part of their script, so it might go unnoticed. Judging from the commands, they do more than just un-gzipping it, but i can't seem to make sense of the gibberish. Anyone mind explaining?

```
#!/bin/sh
skip=44

tab='   '
nl='
'
IFS=" $tab$nl"

umask=`umask`
umask 77

gztmpdir=
trap 'res=$?
  test -n "$gztmpdir" && rm -fr "$gztmpdir"
  (exit $res); exit $res
' 0 1 2 3 5 10 13 15

if type mktemp >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  gztmpdir=`mktemp -dt`
else
  gztmpdir=/tmp/gztmp$$; mkdir $gztmpdir
fi || { (exit 127); exit 127; }

gztmp=$gztmpdir/$0
case $0 in
-* | */*'
') mkdir -p "$gztmp" && rm -r "$gztmp";;
*/*) gztmp=$gztmpdir/`basename "$0"`;;
esac || { (exit 127); exit 127; }

case `echo X | tail -n +1 2>/dev/null` in
X) tail_n=-n;;
*) tail_n=;;
esac
if tail $tail_n +$skip <"$0" | gzip -cd > "$gztmp"; then
  umask $umask
  chmod 700 "$gztmp"
  (sleep 5; rm -fr "$gztmpdir") 2>/dev/null &
  "$gztmp" ${1+"$@"}; res=$?
else
  echo >&2 "Cannot decompress $0"
  (exit 127); res=127
fi; exit $res
ã™>∆Xmpool.sh�•ê]O¬0ÜÔ˜+é—çŸ*à¨„¬(   ëàã„KÑª—≠[a]G€¡¯˜óËÙ¬ΩjÚÙºœ9yOO–í•H≈Ü‰`J
Ä4œœÑHæ£5K#Œ“P˛ò¥çå5K?I¿t†äæ‘«¡9ª»X h%Ω¸'˛‘ˇıkÖLØ™b≠≥BN€j4€÷·¡ç™Z´�Û•^5…eÈ5Ùk⁄ 1ÿ∂]ó‘¬&ÅrÖJK_Á¸JìÉ´ÖUƒÚÓä§1Ÿ‹∏Î[”˘3∫By}˛∏ÿ.m<Ô€=‹õÍ∑—NŸcW/Ù®±MØÂÙ§Zt¶´ß…C˙:¶≥Õ(úÃ¸ÌPΩfËwä˚ÇKã»}¶Ö˘q)ï|çJ
wÄÇpã“º,Ô‹àô“BÓÀ;çw˘î”ºÉ��
```

Comment: The `�` is a non-printable character, IIRC. You should probably provide an encoded string for the compressed payload (hex, base32, base64, etc). Or decompress it yourself and add it to the question. Otherwise, information is lost and folks won't be able to help. You might also be interested in the [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).